# JAR that calls another JARs

Tags: java, path

I'm having some problems with some commands in Java. I created a JAR that needs another JARs to run my app. I had created a batch file to run it with just a click:

```
java -cp Projecto.jar;.\jcommon-1.0.17.jar;.\jfreechart-1.0.14.jar Geral.Client  
pause
```

How can I modify this to make a runable for Linux and Mac OS? Because the command:

```
java -cp Projecto.jar;.\jcommon-1.0.17.jar;.\jfreechart-1.0.14.jar Geral.Client
```

as far as I tried does not work in Linux.

Comment: Hmm have you tried adding the -jar argument? java -jar .... and its too true who wants to answer something they wont even be given acknowledgement for their correct efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path separator in Unix based operating systems is colon `:`, not semicolon `;`. Also the file separator in Unix based operating systems is forwardslash `/`, not backwardslash `\`.

So this should do:

```
java -cp Projecto.jar:./jcommon-1.0.17.jar:./jfreechart-1.0.14.jar Geral.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change slashes: `\` to `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all `semicolons (;)` to `colon (:)` and all `back-slash (\)` to `forward-slash(/)`